# How to filter out observable values based on observable property of each value

Tags: rxjs

Suppose I have an Observable of items

```
let items$ = Observable<Item[]>
```

and each Item has a property `isSelected$`, which itself is an Observable:

```
private isSelected$: Observable<boolean>
```

What would be the best way to receive a list of all items that are currently selected? My solution doesn't look quite right:

```
items$.pipe(
    switchMap(items =>
        combineLatest(items.map(item =>
                item.isSelected$.pipe(
                    map(isSelected => ({item: item, isSelected: isSelected})))),
            map(items => items.filter(item => item.isSelected).map(item => item.item))
        )))
```

It works and I have used it before, but it's such a complicated construct for something I have to do quite often. There must be a better way.

**Note:** The subscriber needs a list of all the selected items, not a stream of individual items.

**Example:**
`items$` would emit the following list:

```
[{id: 1, isSelected$: of(true)}, 
    {id: 2, isSelected$: of(false)}, 
    {id:3, isSelected$: of(true)}]
```

And as a result in our subscribe, we would like to get the list:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 3}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try something like this

```
.pipe(
    switchMap(
        items => from(items).pipe(
            mergeMap(item => item.isSelected$.pipe(map(sel => ({sel, item})))),
            filter(data => data.sel),
            map(data => ({id: data.item.id})),
            toArray()
        )
    ),
)
```

First we take the notification of `items$`, which is an Array, and transform it into an Observable which emits one item at the time.

The key then is in the function passed in as parameter to `mergeMap`.

`item.isSelected` returns the `Observable<boolean>` to be used for filtering. To such Observable we apply a transformation via `map` to turn it into an object which holds 2 properties: the selection criteria and the entire item.

The rest is just filtering based on the selection criteria and then transforming again to return the `item`.

I have tested the above code with the following test data

```
const items$ = of(
    [
        {id: 1, isSelected$: of(true)},
        {id: 2, isSelected$: of(false)},
        {id: 3, isSelected$: of(true)},
        {id: 4, isSelected$: of(true)},
    ],
    [
        {id: 10, isSelected$: of(true)},
        {id: 20, isSelected$: of(true)},
        {id: 30, isSelected$: of(false)},
        {id: 40, isSelected$: of(false)},
    ]
);
```

Comment: That's better than my approach for sure. But, how do you collect all the items as a list in the end? I maybe forgot to explicitely mentioned that the result must be a list of items.

Comment: Maybe the `toArray` operator is what you are looking for

Comment: It seems `toArray` emits when the source observable completes. But I guess `items$` never completes, so do we ever get the array?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it emits when source Observable completes. It is pretty logical if you want to have a list at the end. Could you elaborate more what kind of list you want to get? How this list would look like if `items$` never completes?

Comment: `items$` is a long-lived Observable that emits lists of items. See edit.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect, hopefully, your case. The change is just a reorganization of the pipe. `mergeMap` and following operators are piped into `from(items)` within the most external `switchMap`.

Comment: Hi @Picci thanks for your effort. I like your solution better than mine.

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it did not work.  Here is the Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4fcq5 . @Picci can you please take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I added a button to dynamically select the 1st item, so when pushing that button I expect to see SelectedVMs update.  The vms stream is a BehaviorSubject which could be periodically updated (binding to a listview with paging)

Comment: @Picci the problem seems to be the toArray() is not applicable to a BehaviorSubject.  I tried using buffer() but it needs a stream to tell it when to form the array.  I tried using the checkboxes as a stream input to buffer() but it didn't work.

Comment: @H Dog there several things that do not look right in your example. Here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfbag3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you may see a quick fix I made to make the selection mechanism work. I did not work on the `delay`  but I think you have to consider the timing of the events. Last: I am pretty sure that `toArray` works with BehaviorSubject since this is just a subclass of Observable.